# grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory for NVME dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, xubuntu

Have a regular Xubuntu installation. Recently whenever interacting with apt I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vim is already the newest version (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.

Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.167~18.04.5+2.04-1ubuntu44.1.2) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Note that my system boots fine and I've had no issues.

I've tried uninstalling grub*, reinstalling, and updating grub to no avail. This was the advice in the other posts about this issue.

Partition set up looks like:

```
sudo blkid

/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="<ID>" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="<ID>"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="<ID>" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="<ID>"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="<ID>" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="<ID>"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="<ID>" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="<ID>"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="<ID>" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="<ID>"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: UUID="<ID>" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="<ID>"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="<ID>" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="<ID>"
/dev/nvme1n1: PTUUID="<ID>" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

`mount` shows the following:

```
mount  | grep /dev

udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=16377456k,nr_inodes=4094364,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/nvme1n1p3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
/dev/fuse on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=<id>,group_id=<id>)
```

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme1n1p3 during installation
UUID=<ID> /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
# swap was on /dev/nvme1n1p2 during installation
UUID=<ID> none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=F030-47FA /boot/efi vfat umask=0077,noauto 0 1
```

```
$lsblk -e 7 -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTUUID,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL,UUID

NAME        FSTYPE LABEL PARTUUID                             MOUNTPOINT   SIZE MODEL                                    UUID
nvme1n1                                                                  YYY.YG Samsung SSD              
├─nvme1n1p1 vfat         <ID>              YYYM                                          <ID>
├─nvme1n1p2 swap         <ID> [SWAP]      YY.YG                                          <ID>
└─nvme1n1p3 ext4         <ID> /          YYY.YG                                          <ID>
nvme0n1                                                                  YYY.YG Samsung SSD
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat         <ID>              100M                                          <ID>
├─nvme0n1p2              <ID>               16M                                          
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs         <ID>            YYY.YG                                          <ID>
└─nvme0n1p4 ntfs         <ID>              499M                                          <ID>
```

```
First line of fstab matches `nvme1n1p3`
Second line of fstab matches `nvme1n1p2`
Third line of stab matches `nvme0n1p1`
```

Comment: You are not showing mount of ESP? Mine is like this: `/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime....)` Check fstab. `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` to see if UUID matches and is in fstab.

Comment: the lsblk command is giving me: "unknown column: fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid" if there is a fix for that.

As for the cat fstab ill update post

Comment: Did you copy command or hand copy? I copied & pasted into terminal & it runs in Kubuntu & should work with any Ubuntu flavor. If you leave off partUUID, it also fits better on the screen. Partuuid is only required to know if UEFI is using correct ESP as UEFI uses it.

Comment: I changed it to `lsblk -e 7 -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTUUID,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL,UUID
` and that worked.

Updated the OP, but basically for the non-comment lines of fstab:

First line of fstab matches `nvme1n1p3`. Second line of fstab matches `nvme1n1p2`. Third line of stab matches `nvme0n1p1`.

Comment: Grub reinstall should then use that UUID and find ESP. A few UEFI systems do have some way to lock (security?) on ESP to prevent writing. Check UEFI settings. Or you may need a dosfsck. `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/nvme0n1p1`  see also `man dosfsck`

Comment: "Grub reinstall should then use that UUID and find ESP." When I reinstall it seems to "work", but the apt-get error doesn't go away. I'll try the other commands thanks

Comment: So one issue is that `nvme0n1p1` is the boot partition for windows. I'm trying to make sure ubuntu recognizes the ubuntu boot partition

Comment: Normally Ubuntu & Windows share one ESP. You can change UUID in fstab to ESP on Ubuntu drive and then reinstall grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix I did after some trial and error was:

```
sudo mount /boot/efi 
sudo apt autoremove
```

At this point apt was able to complete it's installation on /boot/efi, and both dual systems in the dual boot work as intended still no change.